# Intersection of two convex set in n-dimensional space

Tags: convex-hull, n-dimensional

Let $X={x_1,\ldots,x_p}$ and $Y={y_1,\ldot,y_q}$ be two set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Is  there a method to find $\mathrm{conv}(X)\cap \mathrm{conv}(Y)$ as $\mathrm{conv}(Z)$, where $Z$ is some subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Please mention what software you are using, if it's not a theoretical question.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com might me more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Matlab.